# Conversion of electrical energy to heat in a circuit

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

How is electrical energy converted to heat in a circuit? I read on quora and other sites that it is due to  how much resistance it receives due to colliding with atoms. However what exactly does it mean to collide with atoms? Is the kinetic energy just transferred to the atom's electrons it interacts with and does that promote the electron to a higher energy state, and when it is de-excited it releases heat in the form of infrared radiation? How does resistance explain why copper is better conductor than iron?

Comment: Looks like you adjusted your old question well! The several questions within this one seem to be related closely enough.

Comment: The only reason was that I saw that you could only post once every 40 minutes so I wanted to get a lot of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is electrical energy converted to heat in a circuit?

[Heat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heat.html) is connected with kinetic energy, the definition of temperature is [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html) and in general it is connected to kinetic energy of particles, atoms and molecules.

In a normal circuit, one expects that the conducting metalic parts do not get heated, and heat appears on resistors, an extreme in  the old electric heaters.

> I read on quora and other sites that it is due to how much resistance it receives due to colliding with atoms. However what exactly does it mean to collide with atoms?

In a usual circuit it is electrons that carry the kinetic energy to be transferred through collision to the atoms/molecules of the resistance

> Is the kinetic energy just transferred to the atom's electrons it interacts with and does that promote the electron to a higher energy state, and when it is de-excited it releases heat in the form of infrared radiation?

No, this may happen but to a very small extent. It is the collisions of electrons with the whole atom that transfers kinetic energy to the atom (molecule), and that kinetic energy is what characterizes temperature and therefore heat transfers/changes. Inelastic collisions mean that the atom will rotate and vibrate in the lattice, and the temperature rises. The lattice although neutral over all, has spill over electric and magnetic fields and quantum mechanical vibrational levels in these fields which will radiate away as an infrared radiation characteristic of the [black body](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) radiation at that temperature.

> How does resistance explain why copper is better conductor than iron?

My guess is that the lattice of iron has some vibrational and rotational levels that can be excited by the transfer of kinetic energy that copper does not. The electrons just scatter elastically in conductors, if one models  at the microscopic level, keeping their energy.( one has to go into the quantum mechanics of conductors for understanding, and the [band theory of solids](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) is a good place to start)

I hope you check the links, and that you realize that you need a course to really understand your question.

Comment: Thank you so much anna v for the answer. However, can you clarify what you mean by an electron hitting an atom. Do you mean it interacts with the electrons in the atom and that's what causes a transfer of kinetic energy, or do you mean that it hits the nucleus? I will definitely take a look into the links that you posted. In order to really understand my question what books or courses should I take. I am entering college. I truly want to have a good understanding of this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean it is atom/molecule electron scattering. The atoms have a spill over electric field (which gives the chemical bonding) with which the electron can scatter, even though neutral overall there are charge distributions . I mean that the scatter tranfers the kinetic energy to the whole atom and thence the lattice

Comment: I am too old to recommend books ( retired in 2000) the hyperphysics link is good for physics questions. Courses: you should follow the recommendation of your advisor, certainly quantum mechanics will be there, and if you are intereted in solids, solid state physics.